# Point free composition of multivariate functions

Tags: haskell, function-composition

Say, we want to introduce the notion of sum of functions of different arguments (let's call it `<+>`), which behaves like the that: `(f1 <+> f2)(x1, x2) == f1(x1) + f2(x2)`.

While this can be easily written out manually, it makes sense to use point-free style with the help of the notion of cartesian product of functions. The latter is defined below and seems alright and quite general to me:

```
x :: (x1 -> y1) -> (x2 -> y2) -> (x1 -> x2 -> (y1, y2))
x f1 f2 = \x1 x2 -> (f1(x1), f2(x2))
```

Then we can write:

```
(<+>):: Num a => (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a)
(<+>) = (uncurry (+)) . x
```

And the code above seems fine to me too, but GHC thinks otherwise:

```text
 * Couldn't match type: (x20 -> y20) -> a -> x20 -> (a, y20)
                     with: ((a -> a) -> a -> a -> a, (a -> a) -> a -> a -> a)
      Expected: (a -> a)
                -> ((a -> a) -> a -> a -> a, (a -> a) -> a -> a -> a)
        Actual: (a -> a) -> (x20 -> y20) -> a -> x20 -> (a, y20)
    * Probable cause: `x' is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of `(.)', namely `x'
      In the expression: (uncurry (+)) . x
      In an equation for `<+>': (<+>) = (uncurry (+)) . x
    * Relevant bindings include
        (<+>) :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
```

It feels like the compiler cannot infer the second function's type, but why? And what am I supposed to do, is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you supply two arguments, you will see what has gone wrong.

```
(<+>) = uncurry (+) . x
(<+>) a = (uncurry (+) . x) a
        = uncurry (+) (x a)
(<+>) a b = uncurry (+) (x a) b
```

Whoops! That `b` gets passed to `uncurry` as a third argument, rather than `x` as a second argument as you probably intended. The third and fourth arguments are also supposed to go to `x` rather than `uncurry`, as in:

```
(<+>) a b c d = uncurry (+) (x a b c d)
```

Here's the correct way to point-free-ify a four-argument composition.

```
\a b c d -> f (g a b c d)
    = \a b c d -> (f . g a b c) d
    = \a b c -> f . g a b c
    = \a b c -> ((.) f . g a b) c
    = \a b -> (.) f . g a b
    = \a b -> ((.) ((.) f) . g a) b
    = \a -> (.) ((.) f) . g a
    = \a -> ((.) ((.) ((.) f)) . g) a
    = (.) ((.) ((.) f)) . g
```

Most people then write this with section syntax as `(((f .) .) .) . g`. Applying this new fact to your case:

```
\a b c d -> uncurry (+) (x a b c d)
    = (((uncurry (+) .) .) .) . x
```

Comment: The definition `(<+>) = (uncurry (+) .) . x` still gives errors.

Comment: Holy crap... THAT's really unreadable. I believe we can consider this a drawback of currying. On top of all, we are forced to think of `x` as of function of 4 arguments, while it's not natural in this situation...

Comment: Maybe we could improve this with some combinations of `curry` and `uncurry4`, but... Really, it breaks all the idea

Comment: @heinwol Ahhh... readable is in the eye of the beholder. ^_^ It certainly is tough to reason through the first time you see it, but at the 100th time it's as easy to read as "the". As for whether thinking of `x` as a function of 4 arguments is natural or not... ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: There is also [`...`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universum-1.7.2/docs/Universum-VarArg.html#v:...) from the universum package which "just works" in this case, but it has an even more magical type.

Comment: @Noughtmare wow, I love things that just work!)) That's cool! It's a pity that my poor understanding of typeclasses don't allow me to comprehend how this stuff works though... Well, all in good time, I hope

Answer (score 2):

The `.` operator is only for composing functions with a single argument, but the function `x` has four arguments, so you have to use `.` four times:

```hs
(<+>) = (((uncurry (+) .) .) .) . x
```

Do keep in mind that this is not considered good style in actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Define

```
compose2 :: (b -> c -> t) -> (a -> b) -> (d -> c) -> a -> d -> t
compose2 p f g x y = p (f x) (g y)
```

Now, `compose2 (+)` is your `<+>`:

```
> :t compose2 (+)
compose2 (+) :: Num t => (a -> t) -> (d -> t) -> a -> d -> t
```

As you can see its type is a bit more general than you thought.

`compose2` [already exists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/util/docs/Util.html#v:compose2).